# How to disable the boot log daemon by editing the init script?

Tags: logs

I understand that boot log daemon (see this question [Starting Bootlog daemon: bootlogd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118687/starting-bootlog-daemon-bootlogd) is a part of the init script. But I don't know how to edit this script to disable this daemon.  Can some one explain the complete procedure to disable it?

**Update**

Unfortunately in my linux flavour (petalinux running on arm cortexA 9 based zynq chip) I could not find the file /etc/default.bootlogd:

```
root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/etc# grep -r "BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" *
init.d/stop-bootlogd:case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
init.d/bootlogd:case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
rc2.d/S99stop-bootlogd:case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
rc3.d/S99stop-bootlogd:case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
rc4.d/S99stop-bootlogd:case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
rc5.d/S99stop-bootlogd:case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
rcS.d/S07bootlogd:case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
```

Now I am unable to understand where should I make change?

Here is the out put of **vi init.d/bootlogd**

```
! /bin/sh
#
# bootlogd      One of the first scripts to be executed. Starts or stops
#               the bootlogd log program. If this script is called as
#               "stop-bootlogd", it will stop the daemon instead of
#               starting it even when called with the "start" argument.
#
# Version:      @(#)bootlogd  2.85-12  21-Mar-2004  miquels@cistron.nl
#

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/sbin/bootlogd
NAME=bootlogd
DESC="Bootlog daemon"

test -f $DAEMON || exit 0

[ -r /etc/default/bootlogd ] && . /etc/default/bootlogd

## set -e # not needed
case "$BOOTLOGD_ENABLE" in
        [Nn]*)
                exit 0
                ;;
esac

STOPPER=
ACTION="$1"
case "$0" in
        *stop-bootlog*)
                STOPPER=Y
                if [ "$ACTION" = start ]
                then
                        ACTION=stop
                fi
                ;;
esac

case "$ACTION" in
        start)
                echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
                if [ -d /proc/1/. ]
                then
                        umask 027
                        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet \
                                --exec $DAEMON -- -r
                else
                        $DAEMON -r
                fi
                echo "$NAME."
                ;;
        stop)
                echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --exec $DAEMON

if [ "$STOPPER" ] && [ -f /var/log/boot ] && \
                   [ -f /var/log/boot~ ]
                then
                        cd /var/log
                        chgrp adm boot
                        savelog -p -c 5 boot > /dev/null 2>&1
                        mv boot.0 boot
                        mv boot~ boot.0
                fi

                echo "$NAME."
                ;;
         restart|force-reload)
                echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --exec $DAEMON
                sleep 1
                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $DAEMON
                echo "$NAME."
                ;;
        *)
                N=${0##*/}
 N=${N#[SK]??}
                echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
                exit 1
                ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If bootlogd is enabled, look at `/etc/default/bootlogd`, you will see:

```
# Run bootlogd at startup ?
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=Yes
```

You can disable it by changing its value to `No`:

```
# Run bootlogd at startup ?
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=No
```

**Update**

`bootlogd` saves messages to `/var/log/boot`. You can change default save file by editing `BOOTLOGD_OPTS` in `/etc/init.d/bootlogd`:

```
BOOTLOGD_OPTS="-r -c -l /root/boot.log"
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me if I make it "yes", where is the log file saved?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I could not find 'default'  directory, see my update

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: petalinux as updated above

Comment: Try to adding `/etc/default/bootlogd` manually and check.

Comment: added but when i restarted the board, this file is now not available in "default"

Comment: You mean `/etc/default/bootlogd` is removed after you restart?

Comment: yes, it is not there, that means, when the system is booting, the file is deleted. but before rebooting I saw that file was indeed there